# Crystal Reports linking modules Data

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a payroll report. We do not use RT in sage, all we need is an exportable report which we upload into another payroll system. The report has to pull data from ABM, PJM, PRM & PRT modules. I can figure out linking ABM to PJM using the PJM_MASTER_Job_Contract list and PRM links to PRT by Employee ID. My issue is that I can’t figure out how to link them all together, we added in a custom field into ABM_MASTER_Person_Custom_Fields which we manually enter in the Employee ID but since it is a custom field it doesn’t recognize that they match.

The report will be ran by Payroll Week Ending date, showing Employee Name, Employee ID, and job information for three types of Pay Id’s & Amounts. It has to look at the PJ Job contact list and pull the ABM contact who has a certain role. Then it will look at the project dates to determine if they should be getting payroll (formulas will determine this)

I have been trying to create subreports but still cant figure out how to pull the right information in them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.